# Knative/Kubernetes unique IP for outbound traffic

Tags: kubernetes, outbound, knative

**Question:**

Does Knative expose low-level network components that allow me to configure the stack in such a way, that each instance has a **unique IP address available for outbound networking**?

**Info**

I have a workload that has to happen on queue event. The incoming event will start the fetching on an API. Due to rate limiting and amount of request (around 100), the process is long-running and with `wait / request / wait / request / wait / ..` . What the code (JS) basically does is, hitting an API endpoint with parameters from the queues message and sending the result of the 100 API requests back with another queue.

Serverless on Lamdba is therefore expensive, also on AWS multiple instances are likely to be spawned on the same VM (tested), resulting in the same IP for outbound traffic. Therefore Lambda is not an option for me.

I read a lot about Knative lately and I imagine that the Kubernetes stack offers better configurability. I need to have concurrent instances of my service, but I need to have a unique outbound IP per instance.

Currently, the solution is deployed on AWS Beanstalk where I scale them out based on queue-length. Therefore 1 - 10 instances exist at the same time and perform the API requests. I use micro instances since CPU/../.. load is really low. There have been multiple issues with Beanstalk, that's why we'd like to move.

I do not expect a monthly cost advantage (IPs are expensive, that's ok), I am just unhappy with the deployment on Beanstalk.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, going with KNative/Kubernetes is probably not the way to proceed here.  You will have to manage a ton of complexity just to get some IP addresses.  Beanstalk will seem like a walk in the park.

Depending on how many IPs you need, you can just setup a few EC2 instances loaded up with IP addresses.  One cheap `t3.small` instance can host 12 IPv4 addresses ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI)) and your JS code can simply send requests from each of the different IP addresses.  (Depending on your JS http client, usually there's a localAddress option you can set.)

Comment: The project wants to lose dependencies on AWS, especially EB. There are deployment issues that require to scale the env. to 0 after a release and then back to x - leading to downtimes of 15 minutes per release. In your example, you miss that IP addresses are so expensive that you can also just spin up 12 micro instances without going down to the network stack at all. We also looked into ECS, but it is too proprietary, so we'll go with Kubernetes - because it seems to be the lowest common denominator that could handle all of the project's components in an open manner. But YES, complexity.....

Comment: Well, at my work we must staff a team of _highly_ paid dev/ops people to build / babysit our not-so-large k8s clusters even though they are managed "on the cloud" at one of the major providers, so yeah from my point of view rigging a dozen AWS elastic IP addresses on an instance (or 12) seems like dirt cheap in comparison.  Scale to zero, etc., aren't difficult to solve in the use case you've provided.